# does any body know where to find free imap client c++ for windows (not libEtpen)

Tags: c++, client, imap

Im working with libetpen for the last 2 days and trying to compile it in VS express without any lack , does any body knows any good easy to use imap c++ free lib ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the oldest and most robust IMAP client libraries is [UW's c-client](ftp://ftp.cac.washington.edu/mail/imap.tar.Z).  It's free.  It provides the IMAP support for mailers like Pine and for platforms like PHP.  The c-client library will almost certainly compile on your platform.  It hasn't been updated much over the past 3 years, but IMAP has largely been static over that period.

The only major drawbacks: It's probably a little lower-level than you'd like, and it's C rather than C++.

Comment: this is good but again very hard to understand how to use it
and why its not support ssl in windows , or it does .